# How to remove formation due to AC water outlet?

Tags: cleaning

I have an air conditioner at my office. But recently I happen to see that its water outlet is dripping down and creating a formation like the one shown below.
[image: hope you get an idea about formation that I mentioned] 
How can I prevent the AC from generating further formations? I also need to remove this formation. Suggest clever and cheap methods.

Comment: AC is going to drip and what is the formation

Comment: For your first question I need more info.  Can you show a pic of where the water comes out?  Is there a hose there? a hole?

Comment: @Paparazzi Formation is as shown in the image, the white formation in between tile gap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formation might be calcium carbonate? Does the water drip directly from the AC, or along a rock before it falls?

I think to get rid of this sediment buildup, just soak a rag in vinegar, then let the rag sit on the affected area. It should re-dissolve with a mild acid like vinegar.

To prevent build-up is a little harder; mainly, try to get the water to drip somewhere else. A short length of hose maybe, to lead it towards a drain? or a stick from a tree touching the water, to convey it to the other side of the railing?

Comment: Yes, it forms a rock like structure and drips down.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I prevent AC from generating further formations?

generally AC units have a port through which water is drained. This water is due to excess air humidity. at the end of port you can attach a pipe which leads water straight to a container (a used bottle is good container as it is very portable).

However while using this hack you will need to remember to remove the water out of bottle on daily basis.

If you are wondering How would you attach pipe. you can use sealing solutions like m-seal wet set. make sure that the solution is waterproof.

[image]

Comment: Have we really fallen so far as a civilization where "run water through a pipe into a container" is now a *hack*?

Comment: @Captainobvious Placing container for dripping water is offcourse not a hack, but when it is in your office having frequent client visits, with newly purchased air conditioner, you are made to use hacks.

Answer (score 0):

For cleaning the calcium formations you can try to use cleaning liquids for bathroom/kitchen.
To prevent of appearance of new layer of formation you can use a piece of hose, attached to the stock outlet by using armored scotch tape. Hose must have bigger diameter than the  outlet's diameter to prevent the cluttering with wet dust or with mustiness or something else. Instead of scotch tape you can use cable tie or the sanitary screw coupling. Point the hose to the closest side of balcony if possible, so people on floors below won't see water on their heads and hand-rails (e.g. when it is windy).
Anoter and faster way is to use plastic bottle with removed bottom - scotch tape, glue, screw through bottle neck etc.